# Linq combine arrays from same object instance

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a class as shown below, in that class there is one to one mapping between Amount array, and date's array indexes, so there length will always be same.

I have to get the maximum amount from Amount[] where Date1 > DateTime.Today & DateTime.Today < Date2 < @OneParameterDate.

How can this be done using linq?

```
public class TestClass
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public decimal[] Amount { get; set; }

        public DateTime[] Date1 { get; set; }

        public DateTime[] Date2 { get; set; }

        public DateTime[] Date3 { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Surely you'd be better off collection of objects with 4 related properties than having 4 collections of values that aren't obviously related to each other? As well as being easier to read, it'd make your problem trivial to solve.

Comment: @CharlesMager I wanted to write the same this moment :D

Comment: Otherwise i think you need a `for` loop which contains shared index between the `Amount`, `Date1` and `Date2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charles Mager's comment points in the correct direction. But if you're not willing to change your code in that way, this should give you the result you want:

```
decimal maxAmount = Enumerable.Range(0, Amount.Length)
    .Where(i => Date1[i] > DateTime.Today &&
                Date2[i] > DateTime.Today &&
                Date2[i] < OneParameterDate)
    .Max(i => Amount[i]);
```

`Enumerable.Range` iterates through the array indices, `Where` filters for those indices where your condition (as I understood it from your question) is met.

From these filtered indices, `Max` selects the maximum amount value.

Comment: Didn't even think about this! Nice

Answer (score 2):

If you can, a better representation will be to have a class like this:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date3 { get; set; }
}
```

And then you have a `IEnumerable<ClassA>` in your `TestClass`. Now You can do linq queries on it.

```
records.Where(record.Date1 < DateTime.Today && 
              DateTime.Today < record.Date2 &&
              record.Date2 < @SomeParameter)
       .Max(record.Amount);
```

Comment: So I have to create one more class which wraps the IEnumerable<ClassA> and ID and Name.

Comment: You can also just do:

public class TestClass
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date2 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date3 { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

And have a collection of the TestClass - however you see better for your model.

Comment: Formatting is bad but basically just removed the arrays from your original object and have a collection of it. The idea is that it isn't a nice way to represent it in 4 different arrays and to have to make sure they are synced

Comment: Sometimes Date1 can be null and Date2 have values, but if both have values then length will be same.

Comment: @Deepak - Could be that for your case it is more correct the way you did at first.

but in general it seems to me that if you use the same index to locate a value in these 4 arrays then you are actually referring to the same "logical object" - and if so - why not to also represent it that way in your code :)

Comment: :) Thanks for the input